# Replace abstract method's parameter type with derived type

Tags: php, parameter-passing, abstract, derived-class

Here is what I've got:

```
<?php
abstract class BasePlayer {
  ...
}

class Player extends BasePlayer {
  ...
}

abstract class BaseRoom {
  abstract public function joinPlayer(BasePlayer $player);
}

class Room extends BaseRoom {
  public function joinPlayer(Player $player) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Long story short, in the declaration I used an abstract (general) class, whilst in the implementation I use a child class of this abstraction. Unfortunately, it throws

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Room::joinPlayer() must be compatible with BaseRoom::joinPlayer(BasePlayer $player)
```

I would be very grateful if you give any suggestions about this problem.

Comment: Change `Room::joinPlayer` to take a parameter of type `BasePlayer` instead of `Player`

Comment: But that's the thing - I don't want any implementation of BasePlayer, just this one. + if I put BasePlayer, the IDE isn't satisfied, says $player doesn't have some methods...

Comment: Unfortunately, that's about all you can do. PHP is limited in that sense. You can try to not have the abstract `BaseRoom::joinPlayer` and just declare it for each class you make, but then you lose the error-checking of the abstract class... this might be the best option if you need your IDE to work properly.

Comment: Thank you, Mark. I hope this will be fixed someday in PHP, because it seems quite logical to me.

Comment: It very well may be, since enforcing types in parameters is fairly new (from PHP 5 I think, which is still the major version in use). It certainly would make abstract classes work that much more like other OOP languages...